# How to display backslash \ literally between two EL expressions without escaping the 2nd expression?

Tags: jsf-2, el

I have a value attribute:

```
value="#{mgdBean.directory}\\ #{mgdBean.file}"
```

I need to trim the white space between directory and file name so that the value appears as:

> Directory\File.

I cannot remove the white space because of the escape sequence `\` which would escape the 2nd EL expression.

Answer (score 6):

Display it with EL as well:

```
value="#{mgdBean.directory}#{'\\'}#{mgdBean.file}"
```

Comment: For me this worked: value="#{mgdBean.directory}#{\"\\\\\"}#{mgdBean.file}" (I use tomcat bundled el-api.jar)